# Clock that doesn't reset on refresh

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make this count down not reset on load or refresh. Can anyone help me with this? I have heard I can use local storage but surly I will need to change this code to be server sided with PHP and MySQL. If you do have any resources which show you the PHP version could you send them to me or post as an answer?

```
var updateTimer = function() {
    timer = localStorage.getItem('timer') || 0;
    if ( timer === 0 ) {
       $("div#timer").html("Timer is unset");
    } else {
       timer--;
       localStorage.setItem('timer', timer);
      $("div#timer").html(timer);
    }
};

$(function() {
    setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    $("#start").click( function() {
        localStorage.setItem('timer', 500);
    });
});
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Thank you

Comment: nice problem. this is a slightly nuts alternative proposal but; instead of using a countdown timer that's relative to zero, you could set a real world target time using: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp and then append that target time to the page url using a query `...com/?target=89719283`. when the page is reloaded the target is checked and countdown continues. maybe useful if you don't want to delve into cookies and local storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely avoid server sided coding, you can save values using Cookies.

In javascript this is easily done by document.cookie = "yourValues, expiryDate".
JQuery also has some nice functions to handle cookies.
You may want to adjust your script to calculate the passed time between loads or not having the clock run, but that is optional.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp <- Here is a simple tutorial on how to use them.

Comment: You could for Instance do something like:

`var updateTimer = function() {
    timer = localStorage.getItem('timer') || 0;
    if ( timer === 0 ) {
       $("div#timer").html("Timer is unset");
    } else {
       timer--;
       document.cookie = "timerValue="+timer+"; createdAt="+new Date() +";"
       localStorage.setItem('timer', timer);
      $("div#timer").html(timer);
    }
};`

This will set your cookie, then you just have to check if the cookie for timerValue exists upon initializing. createdAt can be used to calculate how much time has passed since last update.

Comment: I suggest using JQuery, also. This here will make handling cookies easier: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Thanks for you help but I'm still none the wiser haha

Answer (score 0):

With php you can use the cookie's to achieve the same.

```
setcookie($timer);  // Set timer
$_COOKIE['timer'];  // Get timer
```

You can start inserting into mysql in every refresh but use $_COOKIE to show. Mysql is just for tracking and getting correct time after refresh the page.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET timer = '$timer'");  // Inserting every refresh
```

So when page loads either get form stored cookie or retrieve from mysql table

But **COOKIES** will be faster than using only mysql method(It won't work properly as it need to request every second)

Comment: How would I go about implementing the cookies?